# Getting information regarding partition-indexes in sap hana database

Tags: sql, hana

I am using SAP HANA db engine. There are some tables created with partitioning(range partitioning, hash partitioning, etc) in the database. I have a requirement wherein I need to get the information of the partition-indexes such as column partitioned, type of partition, intervals that are set for partitioning, etc given the table name by querying over a system-table or a stored-proc or otherwise. Any help in reaching this need is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the documentation on system tables and look into

- M_TABLES
- M_CS_TABLES
- TABLES and
- M_CS_PARTITIONS

e.g. here https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/ad3d1075191014bce8aba8320b5b94/content.htm?frameset=/en/21/0197377519101481cfb213f0b84848/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/2e/1ef8b4f4554739959886e55d4c127b/plain.htm&node_id=347